# How to remember toggle status of child menu

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

In the left pane, there are some menus, some are children of another, when I expand the parent menu then click one child, the whole page refresh, then the parent menu collapse, I want the parent menu keep expand, how?

the NavigationProvider is as following:

```
AddItem(
  new MenuItemDefinition(
     "AllUsers",
      L("AllUsers"),
      icon: "menu"
     ).AddItem(
       new MenuItemDefinition(
          PageNames.LPSellers,
          L("Sellers"),
          url: "Sellers",
          icon: "people",
          requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Sellers
          )
```

Comment: ASP.NET Core + MPA? Template version?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266353/admin-burger-menu-should-remain-expanded-if-a-submenu-item-is-selected?s=2|27.7788